# .htaccess rewrite error from www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA]
```

I am trying to force HTTPS, and www.domain.com should redirect to domain.com.

What I get is that domain.com properly rewrites to https://domain.com/ and displays files in the /public folder, but www.domain.com redirects to https://domain.com//public/

The public folder should not be visible in the address, but files should still be pulled from it.

www.domain.com points to domain.com, and this .htaccess file is stored in the webroot of domain.com

**EDIT: The issue was with something outside of the control of the website.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last rule to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/($|public/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA]
```